# Show that if $x$ is non-negative and $x_n$ is a non-negative sequence converging to $x$ then $\sqrt{x_n}\to\sqrt{x}$ as $n\to\infty$

Tags: analysis

So I've let $|x_n-x| < \epsilon$ but am not sure where to go now. 
I know
$\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}$, but I'm not sure how to use that.

Comment: ayy lmao keith ball?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For $x = 0$ this is easy. So let $x \neq 0$. Then $$\left\vert \frac{x_n - x}{\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}} \right\vert\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \left \vert x_n - x\right\vert$$ and $\frac {1}{\sqrt x}$ is a constant.

Comment: I know why it's true, but is there a reason you've chose to make ≤ 1/x^0.5, or is it simply to make it nice and you know x is non-negative, so must be true?

Comment: @AnoUser1 It's using $\sqrt{x_n}\ge 0\implies\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\le\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to force $|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|<\delta$, with arbitrarily small $\delta>0$. If $x=0$ take $\epsilon=\delta^2$. If $\epsilon\le x$ so that $x\ne 0$, we have $$|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|=\frac{|x_n-x|}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}\le\frac{\epsilon}{\sqrt{x}},$$so it suffices to take $\epsilon<\delta\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: You say We want to force |√xn −√x|<δ, is this allowed? It looks to me like assuming what you want to prove is true

Comment: @AnoUser1 "We want to force" means "we want to prove"; that statement was a way to introduce the symbol $\delta$. I've not assumed the inequality we wished to force; I've pointed out how to choose $\epsilon$ so as to prove the desired result.

Comment: Got it. One last bit, how does ϵ<δ√x help us? I get that |√xn−√x| needs to be less than a constant for all x, and δ√x is a constant but why epsilon less than this?

Comment: @AnoUser1 The point of the exercise is to prove for any $\delta>0$ there exists some $\epsilon>0$ such that $|x_n-x|<\epsilon\implies|\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}|<\delta$. You can choose any $\epsilon$ *that works*; it turns out that one does.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x>0$. Then, since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n} + \sqrt{x}}$ is bounded, you have that $\sqrt{x_n} - \sqrt{x} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. The case $x=0$ is easier.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $x > 0$. Since $x_n \rightarrow x$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and also $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}}$ is finite, then $$\sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{x_n-x}{\sqrt{x_n}+\sqrt{x}} \rightarrow 0$$
$$\implies \sqrt{x_n}-\sqrt{x} = 0 \ \text{ as } \ n \rightarrow \infty$$